# Creating a command prompt and then control some string methods to do

Tags: c#, interpreter

I wanted to do my program like a command prompt. I thought that it must perform some string methods.

For example: `COM> length "string "` must return the length of "string " (the command must be bigger than three characters, that is, len "asdf" is OK). In addition to this I added three methods, "reverse", "ToUpper" and "ToLower" and to escape, "quit", and it is not necessarily adjecent or not (can be any spaces between the command and the string).

I wrote on my way, but I think it is not optimized. So do you have any trick to make it faster and reusable?

(I didn't care about any exception so I know there are some exceptions.)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str;
        for (; ; )
        {
            Console.Write("CSD>");
            str = Console.ReadLine();
            if (str == "quit")
                break;
            commandControl(str);
        }
    }

    public static void commandControl(string str)
    {
        string strCom, strString;
        int index;

        str = str.Trim();
        index = str.IndexOf(" ");

        strCom = str.Substring(0, index);
        str = str.Substring(index);
        str = str.Trim();
        strString = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);

        string[] strComArry = { "length", "reverse", "upper", "lower" };
        int i;

        if (strCom.Length >= 3)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < strComArry.Length; i++)
                if (strCom.Length <= strComArry[i].Length)
                    if (strCom == strComArry[i].Substring(0, strCom.Length))
                        break;

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine(strString.Length);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    for (int j = strString.Length - 1; j >= 0; --j)
                        System.Console.Write(strString[j]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(strString.ToUpper());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(strString.ToLower());
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Command must be more than 3 characters !...");
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are creating is called an interpreter. There are already many questions on Stack Overflow about how to do that; try searching on Google or in the "search" box at the top right of the page. If you want to improve your interpreter, start by investigating tokenizing and lexical analysis. Good luck.

Comment: What is the purpose of your application? Is this homework or simply something you are creating for yourself?

Comment: ı just thought it that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to provide a full working example, but take a look at the snippet below. This idea is to use a dictionary of actions to store what to do with commands. That way, you can add new functionality to the interpreter by adding to the "Methods" dictionary.

The idea is call `InitializeFunctions` to register all of the functions you want available in the interpreter, and then call command control to interpret one.

(I gave two examples on how to add functions, a lambda syntax and referencing a normal function. Also those functions assume you have already parsed what is a command and what is a parameter, which you have done already in your example.)

```
    static Dictionary<string, Action<string>> Methods = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>();

    public static void InitializeFunctions()
    {
        Methods.Add("ToLower", a => Console.WriteLine(a.ToLower()));
        Methods.Add("ToUpper", ToUpper);
    }

    static void ToUpper(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToUpper());
    }

    public static void commandControl(string str, string param)
    {
        if(str.Length < 4)
            Console.WriteLine("Command must be more than 3 characters !...");
        if (Methods.ContainsKey(str))
            Methods[str].Invoke(param);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Command");
    }
```